# Open landscape mode for camera and library

Tags: ios, swift

How I could open the photos and the camera library in landscape mode:

I am using this code for open in portrait now:

```
@IBAction func openLibrary(sender: AnyObject) {        ///accion del boton Library

    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated:true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func openCamera(sender: AnyObject) {        ///accion del boton Camara


    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera



    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated:true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code isn't working on landscape?

Comment: The camera and library is open in portraid with this code, when you rotate the device to landscape gives and error, the application close.

Comment: The error is in:
 class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

In red appear: Thread 1 signal